# Save data into two table. Student with ID “None” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-database

I tried to save data to the standard User class and for my Student class. But I've got a problem.

**Student with ID “None” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?**
I don't really know how to save these data.

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    studentIndex = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    studentName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    studentSurname = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    studentPhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='+48')
    studentPesel = models.CharField(max_length=11, default='')
    studentStudyMode = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='')
    studentFaculty = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    studentSemester = models.IntegerField(default='')
    studentAddress = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    studentMotherName = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    studentBirth = models.DateField(help_text='year-month-day')
    studentEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=255, default='')
    studentImage = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    studentPassword = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='12345678',
                                       help_text='Do not modify this field. Password will be generated automatically')
    studentDateJoined = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        default_password = str(self.studentBirth)[0:4] + str(self.studentBirth)[5:7] + \
                           str(self.studentBirth)[8:10] +\
                           self.studentMotherName[0] +\
                           lower(self.studentName[0])
        User.objects.create_user(username=self.studentIndex, email=self.studentEmail, password=default_password,
                                 first_name=self.studentName, last_name=self.studentSurname)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.studentIndex} - {self.studentName} {self.studentSurname}'
```

When I try this

```
...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        default_password = str(self.studentBirth)[0:4] + str(self.studentBirth)[5:7] + \
                           str(self.studentBirth)[8:10] +\
                           self.studentMotherName[0] +\
                           lower(self.studentName[0])
        Student.objects.create() # <- this one
        User.objects.create_user(username=self.studentIndex, email=self.studentEmail, password=default_password,
                                 first_name=self.studentName, last_name=self.studentSurname)
```

I've got **string index out of range** error (IndexError) or maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison (RecursionError)

I'm new in Django, so I'll be grateful if you'll help me
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it. All I need to do this. I modified my code a little bit.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            default_password = str(self.studentBirth)[0:4] + str(self.studentBirth)[5:7] + \
                               str(self.studentBirth)[8:10] +\
                               self.studentMotherName[0] +\
                               lower(self.studentName[0])
            Student.objects.create()
            User.objects.create_user(username=self.studentIndex, email=self.studentEmail, password=default_password,
                                     first_name=self.studentName, last_name=self.studentSurname)
            super(Student, self).save() # <- this is my solve
        except IndexError:
            print('IndexError')
        except RecursionError:
            print('RecursionError')
```

Answer (score 2):

@dannycrief, the error of kind "..id with None doesn't exist" occurs because django model needs a primary key for record identification and thus automatically adds a "models.Autofield(primary_key = True)" for the same purpose.

When we get the mentioned error, the same indicate that django cannot fetch the primary key. We can resolve it by adding primary_key+True in one of our fields.

Comment: It's too late, but thank you for your answer Rahul!